# Writing Python equivalent of Perl code

Tags: python, perl, http

I don't know a single thing of perl but from a big perl script, I managed to get the relevant parts and make a HTTP request. So, this perl code works perfectly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;

my $request = "X-CTCH-PVer: 0000001\r\n";

my $method_url =  "http://localhost:8088/ctasd/GetStatus";
my $response = $ua->request (POST $method_url,Content => $request);

my $data = $response->status_line . "\n";
print $data;
print $response->content;
```

The above code outputs:

```
200 OK
X-CTCH-PVer: 0000001
```

From my understanding, it's doing a POST to a URL with the specified data. With that base, my python code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib

url = "http://localhost:8088/ctasd/GetStatus"
data = urllib.urlencode([("X-CTCH-PVer", "0000001")])

print urllib.urlopen(url, data).read()
```

But, this returns response as:

```
X-CTCH-Error: Missing protocol header "X-CTCH-PVer"
```

Please help me in making a Python equivalent of perl code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the actual thing was, the `$request` in Perl was literally been sent as POST data without any change. Now I get why is the name `content` in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib

url = "http://localhost:8088/ctasd/GetStatus"
print urllib.urlopen(url, "X-CTCH-PVer: 0000001").read()
```

Worked. I actually found out about this after capturing the traffic in both cases and analysing it in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are not sending the header, you are making/sending a urlencoded string, hence the function `urllib.urlencode`

Try setting the request with actual headers:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2


request = urllib2.Request("http://localhost:8088/ctasd/GetStatus", headers={"X-CTCH-PVer" : "0000001"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: That gives 404 not found. The program that has this API is really sucky at giving error information so this headers error might be deceiving.